# Compare two lists and return a matching set iteratively

Tags: python, list, set, python-itertools

So it's easy to compare to get matching values for when you have two lists, i.e

```
set(a) & set(b)
```

But how would I do it in a function, i.e. when I have n lists, which depends on the input parameter n?

Comment: Just combine all of them in the same way? I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: How do I write it in a function so that the function connects them on its own if the number of lists is arbitrary? The problem is that if the function always outputs 2 lists then the code above is just copy paste, but it wont work if there is 6 lists.

Comment: Can you please give an example of some input and expected output? I understand "I have n lists", but not "which depends on the input parameter n". Is ``n`` a number that is actually passed to "your" function? How do the lists depend on it?

Comment: How would you do it if the input were integers and you wanted to multiply them together?

Answer (score 1):

The below will get the intersection of the first set with rest of the sets.

Is that what you are looking for?

```
def do_it(*sets):
   return set.intersection(*sets)


print(do_it({1, 2, 34}, {3, 6, 8, 34}, {3, 65, 86, 34}))
```

output

```
{34}
```

Comment: If the items are sets, then ``set.intersection(*sets)`` should be enough.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi code was modified. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what `functools.reduce` is for

```
from functools import reduce

total = reduce(set.intersection, map(set, list_of_lists))
```

This is just a pre-defined function that wraps the idea of doing the following:

```
total = set()
for x in list_of_lists:
    total &= set(x)
```

Comment: ``set.intersection`` accepts arbitrary man items as long as the first is a ``set`` – ``set.intersection(*map(set, list_of_lists))`` should be sufficient, there is no need for ``reduce``. Using ``operator.__or__`` would require ``reduce``.

Comment: I'm aware of that; I posted an answer with `reduce` because it is generalizable to any operator.